# How to receipt print (EPSON TM-T81) in ASP.NET Web aplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, epson, receipt

I am working on asp.net application. I have `EPSON TM-T81` receipt printer.

I want to develop functionality for receipt print using EPSON printer with `Asp.net Application` with `C#`.

I don't have any idea about this.Guide me how can i achieve this functionality.

**If anyone have sample code so, provide a link for the same.**

Comment: the first decision will depend on whether you can install and use it as a Windows printer, and consequently use the print functionality of the framework, or do you need to communicate with the printer directly over its RS-232 or USB, thus "roll your own driver"? Are you talking about a server-side or client-side scenario?

Comment: I am taking server-side scenario.I am using this printer using `USB`.

Comment: You have at least two options: A. install the printer in Windows and print to it using all printing-related .NET functionality, including `System.Drawing`; most printers can be configured to activate their cutter on `EndPage`, so you might get away without any raw printer commands; B. [consider this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390313/pos-application-development-receipt-printing?rq=1)

Comment: @ManishSharma . Sir i'm facing the Exact Problem. Could you help me with this if you have found a way out. Thank you.